# Select the best record possible

Tags: algorithm, selection

The problem is to select the most appropriate record within a group of records about 500 in number. That is essentially the demographic selection to show a particular text to customers.
In the example given, if a male customer from USA and California state want to show 'Text 3' but from other states want to show 'Text 2'.
But if it is a female customer from USA/California/SanJose then show 'text 5'. But if the female customer is from other cities show 'Text 4' and if a female customer is not from California, show 'text 1'.

Likewise, I have about 15 attributes with which I have to choose the correct text to display.
What is the best way of doing this? How would I know which attribute is giving 'no match' and make it 'all' in the next pass? And I want to do it efficiently as there would be about 500+ rows.

[Selection Algo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmalO.jpg)

1. List item

Comment: Every customer coming to the system would have 15 attributes which needs to be sifted through and make the best possible selection.

Comment: Even the most naive implementation would probably run in the order of `number of rows * number of attributes` and 500 * 15 is not a big number. Don't worry about performance. First make it work, then make it fast (once you have measured that it is not fast enough).